# Reading files in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, file

We haven't learned about how to read and write files yet, but we have been provided with a premade method that is suppose to read a txt file. The problem is that it doesn't seem to work. This is the premade method that was given to us.

```
/******************************************************************************
 *
 * Filename :     GradeCalculatorFromFile.java.
 * Author:        xxxxxxxxxxx
 * Date:          09/025/2011
 * Description:  This program computes the scores of a list of students in the CSE155a class
 *
 ******************************************************************************/
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;

/* Provide a description of the class */
public class GradeCalculatorFromFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Declare and initialise the variables as needed
      /* The following code enables the user to accept input from the keyboard. Keep this code as it is. */
        Scanner scanner = null;
        try {
            scanner = new Scanner(new File("grades.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Error opening file. Please make sure that you have a grades.txt file in the same folder as GradeCalculator.class");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        /*
        Add your code here to read the number of students and the scores
        Use scanner.next() to read a String
        Use scanner.nextInt() to read an int
        */
    }
}
```

Now, the instructions tell us to place the grades.txt in the same folder as GradeCalculatorFromFile.class. I do this, but I get the error message "Error opening file. Please make sure that you have a grades.txt file in the same folder as GradeCalculator.class". Is there something wrong with the method? I'm using eclipse, and I place the grades.txt file in C:\Users\xxxx\workspace\Homework 3\bin

Comment: Google how to get the current path of the program as a string. Then output the path and that should give you a reference of where you need to put your file.

Comment: Dont paste it bin .. move it to root dir of your project. else provide the complete path

Comment: From what I remember in Eclipse you need to pace your resources at project level directory, not bin subdirectory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse sets the working directory to the project directory. Put the file to

> C:\Users\xxxx\workspace\Homework 3

and it should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably that Eclipse is running the program from a different working directory than the one that you think it is.  Try running the program from the command line by cding into the proper directory and running "java GradeCalculator.class"

That should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving it into the `Homework 3` directory.  If you were using the `javac` and `java` commands to compile and run your program, you'd be correct to co-locate the grades.txt file and the compiled class file.  Eclipse, however, modifies the class path to something non-default.

Answer (score 1):

You must put the file in the root of your src path, and then read it using "/grades.txt"

Answer (score 0):

You have two options: either, move the file to your project directory

```
C:\Users\xxxx\workspace\Homework 3\
```

because that's what Eclipse sets its current working directory to.

Your second option is to open the file as a resource stream

```
Scanner scanner = null;
scanner = new Scanner(
              GradeCalculatorFromFile.class.getResourceAsStream("grades.txt"));
```

This assumes your file is present next to your `GradeCalculatorFromFile.class` (like it already is right now) i.e. available on your `CLASSPATH`.